How to allow changing URL parameter on same component?
In my Angular app, I want to prevent the user from navigating away from a component by using a CanDeactivateGuard.
But I want the user to allow to navigate to a different url parameter id within FeatureBComponent. After adding a CanDeactivateGuard, it blocks every path change. To allow the path parameter change, I came across the RunGuardsAndResolvers config parameter.
But that only supports ignoring query and matrix parameters, not path parameters.
I also tried to tackle ignoring the path parameter change in the guard itself by checking the nextState parameter, but nextState.url still gives back the current URL. So that cannot be used to check.
So in short, how can I allow the user to navigate between
/overview/1

/overview/2

but not
/someotheroute

?

could you please provide a minimal code stackblitz of the issue happening, steps to replicate and desired output from the stackblitz, it will be good for debugging.

sure thing - look at Stackblitz example, see README.md for the steps

just define a function (if your component is called "OverViewComponent"
export const yourGuardFunction: CanDeactivateFn<OverViewComponent> = (
  component: OverViewComponent,
  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
  nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
) => nextState.url.startsWith('/overview/');

And use
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'overview/:id', component: OverViewComponent, canDeactivate: [yourGuardFunction] },
  ...
]


This solution works. But in my understanding, the need to rely on the nextState.url is a missing feature / leaking abstraction in Angulars route config. Why does Angular run the DeactivateGuard in the first place, if the changed route will not deactivate/reinstantiate the same component?
Now the component needs to have knowledge about its URL, while that’s already the responsibility of the route config.
